# VBA Compile Error: Expected Named Parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA's and have pieced together this macro from various searches on "how to filter between two specific dates in excel."  I am trying to have it read the dates from two cells and restrict the shown data to data between those dates.  The input data to the workbook is a SQL table that will be growing over time, so I need the left bound of the range to be the last row with a value in it.  Each line in my AutoFilter part returns an "Expected Named Parameter" error with the := sign highlighted.  From the forums I have read this is due to using VBA reserved words as variable names, but I not think that is the case in this instance.
Here is my code:

```
Public Sub MyFilter()
.AutoFilterMode = False
Dim datRight, datLeft As Date
Dim lastRow As Long
datLeft = Range("J1").Value
datRight = Range("J2").Value
lastRow = Range("A:A").Find("*", Range("A2"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7,
Criteria1:=">=" & datLeft, _
Operator:= xlAnd,
Criteria2:="<=" & datRight, VisibleDropDown:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first error you will get is at the line `.AutoFilterMode = False` Notice the DOT before Autofilter. You have to qualify it with the relevant sheet. For example, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False`
2. When you are trying to find the lastrow using `*`, Always use the method as mentioned in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) post else you will get an error if the worksheet is blank.
3. Your declaration `Dim datRight, datLeft As Date`. In VBA only the last variable will be declared as `Date` and the first one will be declared as `Variant`. Change it to `Dim datRight As Date, datLeft As Date` Also if the `J1` and `J2` values are not date values then you will get an error.

Now to your problem. You are getting that error because you the missing the continuation character `_`

Try this

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, _
Criteria1:=">=" & datLeft, _
Operator:=xlAnd, _
Criteria2:="<=" & datRight, VisibleDropDown:=True
```